# Where's the php-src/PHP-Internals Main Entry Point

Tags: php, php-internals

What function or bit of code serves as the main entry point for executing/interpreting a PHP program in the [source of PHP itself](https://github.com/php/php-src)?  Based on things I've googled or read in books, I know that PHP is designed to work with a server of some kind (even the CLI command works by starting up "the command line SAPI", which acts as a mini-server designed to process a single request), and that the server will ask PHP to execute a program.

I know about the `minit` and `rinit` lifecycle functions, which serve as entry points for a **PHP extension**.

What I don't know is where does the PHP source code have this conversation with itself

> Hey look, there's a PHP program in this file/string.  I ought to run it

I'm not trying to accomplish any specific task here. I'm trying to understand how the internals of PHP does what it does, and find a main entry point where I can start following its execution.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cli/php_cli.c#L1195) is where the CLI starts and [this](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cli/php_cli.c#L1011) is where it starts processing a PHP file whose name is provided in the command line. And so on.

Comment: @axiac thank you! I'm happy to mark that as the best answer if you make it an official response and not just a comment.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### Where is the entry point of the code of some SAPI?

The **CLI** is a standalone application. As any other application written in C, its entry point is the function `main()` (file [`sapi/cli/php_cli.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c), line [`1200`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c#L1200)):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

There are two versions of the CLI for Windows, one of them is a console application and starts with the `main()` function described above, the other is a Windows GUI application (it doesn't create a console when it starts and uses message boxes for output) that starts with the `WinMain()` function (file [`sapi/cli/php_cli.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c), line [`1198`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c#L1198)).
`main()` and `WinMain()` use the same code here. They have different name and different code fragments here and there by checking if the symbol `PHP_CLI_WIN32_NO_CONSOLE` is defined. It is defined in file [`sapi/cli/cli_win32.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cli/cli_win32.c) that is used to generate the Windows GUI application.
`</Windows>`

The **CGI** version is also a standalone console application. Its entry point is also the `main()` function in file [`sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c), line [`1792`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c#L1792).

Similar, the **FPM** version starts with `main()` in file [`sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c), line [`1570`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L1570).

**Apache2 handler** is a dynamically loadable module (`.dll` on Windows, `.so` on Unix-like systems). It registers some functions as event handlers for the events published by the web server (server start, pre/post configuration loaded, process request etc). These handlers are registered by the `php_ap2_register_hook()` function in file [`sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L738), line [`738`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L738).
*(You can find details about how a loadable module integrates with Apache in the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/developer/modguide.html)*.)

The handler that is interesting to us is the function [`php_handler()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L566) that is invoked to handle a HTTP request.

In a similar manner, every SAPI has an entry point (either `main()` or a function that is invoked by the web server).

All these entry points do similar processing:

- initialize themselves;
- parse the command line arguments (only if it's **CLI**, **CGI** or other kind of standalone application);
- read `php.ini` and/or other configuration they have (the Apache module configuration can be overridden in `.htaccess`);
- create a stream using the input file and pass it to the function [`php_execute_script()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/main/main.c#L2496) defined in file [`main/main.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/main/main.c), line [`2496`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/main/main.c#L2496);
- cleanup and return an exit code to the calling process (the shell or the web server).

#### Where is the code that actually executes a PHP script?

The function [`php_execute_script()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/main/main.c#L2496) is a wrapper; it interprets the `php.ini` configuration entries [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [`auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), prepares the list of files (auto-prepend file, main script, auto-append file) and passes the list to [`zend_execute_scripts()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend.c#L1476) that processes them.

`php_execute_script()` is not always invoked, some SAPIs and command line arguments of the CLI produce the direct invocation of `zend_execute_scripts()`.

[`zend_execute_scripts()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend.c#L1476) is where the interesting things happen.

It [compiles](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend.c#L1490) the PHP file (and returns a list of [OP codes](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php) in `op_array` then, if the compilation succeeds (the returned `op_array` is not `NULL`) it [executes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend.c#L1496) the OP-codes. There is also exception handling and cleanup; boring work but as important as the parsing and executions nevertheless.

The compilation is a tedious process. It is done by the function `zendparse()` defined in the file `Zend/zend_language_parser.c`. The definition of the `zendparse()` function and the file `Zend/zend_language_parser.c` are nowhere to be seen in the Git repo; the parser is generated using `bison` and `re2c` that read the language syntax rules and the definition of lexical tokens from [`Zend/zend_language_parser.y`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) and [`Zend/zend_language_scanner.l`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l) and generate the actual compiler in file `Zend/zend_language_parser.c`.

However, even if the hard work is not visible in the repo, the interesting parts of the compilation process are visible in the files mentioned above.

The execution of the compiled script (the list of OP codes) is done by function `zend_execute()` that is defined in the file [`Zend/zend_vm_execute.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h). This is also a generated file and the interesting part is that it is generated by a PHP script.

The generator script ([`Zend/zend_vm_gen.php`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_gen.php#L46)) uses [`zend_vm_def.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_def.h) and [`zend_vm_execute.skl`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_execute.skl) to generate [`zend_vm_execute.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h) and [`zend_vm_opcodes.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_opcodes.h).

[`zend_vm_def.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_vm_def.h) contains the actual interpreter code that is executes to handle each OP code.

#### Where is the code of some function provided by the PHP core or one of its bundled extensions?

The code of the PHP functions and functions provided by extensions is somehow easier to follow. The functions included in the PHP core are located in files in the [`ext/standard`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/php-7.2.2/ext/standard) directory, the functions provided by other extensions are located in files in the corresponding [`ext`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/php-7.2.2/ext) subdirectories.

In these files, the C functions that implement PHP functions are declared using the `PHP_FUNCTION()` macro. For example, the implementation of the PHP function [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) 
starts in file [`ext/standard/string.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/standard/string.c), line [`1948`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/standard/string.c#L1948). The function [`strchr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strchr.php) being an alias of [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) is declared using the `PHP_FALIAS()` macro in file [`ext/standard/basic_functions.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L2833) on line [`2833`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L2833).

And so on, and so forth.

Comment: This is a glorious answer, and well beyond what I expected.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I wish I could bring you to meetings. Excellent response!